# Transforming a list of objects into a table in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I am trying to get the json data (in form of a list of key-value pairs) in one of my data table cells and convert that into a dynamic table of sorts.

```
T
| where id == "xyz"
| project telem_obj
```

The data in the telem_obj cell is of the format

[
  {
    "Value": "SomeKey01",
    "Key": "0"
  },
  {
    "Value": "SomeKey02",
    "Key": "1"
  }
]

My end objective is to get a table of the form;

```
|Key         | Value |
|SomeValue01 | 0     |
|SomeValue02 | 1     |
```

I have managed to do this by taking out the static data and creating atable out of it.

```
print EnumVals = dynamic(
    [
      {
        "Value": "SomeKey01",
        "Key": "0"
      },
      {
        "Value": "SomeKey02",
        "Key": "1"
      }
    ]
)
| mvexpand EnumVals
| evaluate bag_unpack(EnumVals)
```

I am not sure how can I go about taking result of my query, extracting this list of json objects from it and convert it into a new dynamic table. I cannot find any example which works on a list of objects.

Comment: what is the datatype of the `telem_obj` column? if it's `string`, you can use `parse_json()` to make it a `dynamic`, then use your solution at the bottom of your message. If it's already `dynamic`, could you elaborate why your solution at the bottom of your message doesn't provide the expected result?

Comment: Thanks for answering. My mistake was trying to fit the query in the dynamic


    print EnumVals = dynamic(
      T
      | where id == "xyz"
      | project telem_obj
    )
    | mvexpand EnumVals
    | evaluate bag_unpack(EnumVals)

Answer (score 3):

After a good night's sleep, i found how to do it

```
T
| take 1 
| mvexpand telem_obj
| evaluate bag_unpack(telem_obj)
| project Value, Key
```

my mistake was I was trying to force the actual query inside a `dynamic` function.

```
print EnumVals = dynamic(
  T
  | where id == "xyz"
  | project telem_obj
)
| mvexpand EnumVals
| evaluate bag_unpack(EnumVals)
```